# Mailchimp success message within input field?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I've been searching forever to find a solution, but can't find anything. I'm still new to JS. Here is what I have so far - http://jsfiddle.net/WarrenBee/GLb4u/

I want my form to replace the typed text in the input area with a success/fail message, similar to the form on this website: http://momentskis.com/#cols

I don't want a page reload or a pop-up message.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is, to put your event handler code into document.ready

```
$(function(){
    /// Your event bindings and other code
});
```

The reason for that: When your javascript runs, the DOM is not finished loading, and all jquery selectors return empty.

You need to call your JS after DOM is finished, and `$(function(){});` makes it so.

Here is working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/GLb4u/5/

Comment: Thanks! Now how do I place my success message into the input field where I typed my email address?